# Apache Camel - Read JDBC dataSource properties from file

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

i'm using Apache Camel and i try to load datasource properties from this file

**config.properties:**

```
url = my_url
user = user_name
password = user_pass
```

this is dataSource (**blueprint.xml**):

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
      <property name="URL" value="my_url"/>
      <property name="user" value="user_name"/>
      <property name="password" value="user_pass"/>
  </bean>
```

How can i read values from config.properties and insert them into dataSource properties ?

Comment: If your question is really about Spring, then the question should not be annotated with `blueprint-osgi`.

Comment: You see Spring in my post ?!

Comment: Nope, but the first answer assumed you were using Spring and you did not object. ( assumed you were the one who up-voted it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You talk about blueprint.xml, and camel, so I assume you are in an osgi container like Karaf/ServiceMix, and you are using Aries Blueprint.

Then you can use the `cm` namespace and a `property-placeholder`. If you use camel and want your properties to be dynamically reloaded, then you can use too an update strategy `reload`, which start/stop the blueprint container when the configuration change. This will load the configuration with pid "datasource" (ie, in karaf, the file `etc/datasource.cfg`) :

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.2.0"
           xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.2.0">

  <cm:cm-properties id="myProps" persistent-id="datasource" update-strategy="reload"/>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
      <property name="URL" value="${url}"/>
      <property name="user" value="${user}"/>
      <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
  </bean> 
</blueprint>
```

If you want to use your configuration file without using ConfigurationAdmin or dynamically reload your bundle, then you can use the `ext` namespace :

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.2.0">

    <ext:property-placeholder>
        <ext:location>file:config.properties</ext:location>
    </ext:property-placeholder>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
          <property name="URL" value="${url}"/>
          <property name="user" value="${user}"/>
          <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
     </bean> 
</blueprint>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to code I assume you use probably spring as container. General solution in spring is to use PropertyPlaceHolder, your configuration will look like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>config.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
  <property name="URL" value="${jdbc.myUrl}"/>
  <property name="user" value="${jdbc.user_name}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.user_pass}"/>
</bean>
```

Please check the [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/) for details.

Comment: blueprint is strongly inspired by Spring, but it's not compatible ;-)